# How to hide div element on hover of mouse in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#mouse',
  data: {
    showByIndex: null
  }, 
  methods: {

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="mouse">
  <div class="parent" v-for="i in 1" @mouseover="showByIndex = i" @mouseout="showByIndex = null">
    <div class="child-one">
      Some dummy text
    </div>
    <div class="child-two" v-show="showByIndex === i">
      Show me only on hover on "div.parent" element
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example:- https://codepen.io/dhanunjayt/pen/XWgyqXW

With the above code i am able to show the text, when hover of the div element. But small issue is when hover first element should not reflect.

Comment: So you want the div with `child-two` to only show when "Some dummy text" is hovered but not when itself is hovered?

Comment: @JHeth No I think he wants it to only show when the div is hovered, but not the `some dummy text`. This may be solvable by `e.stopPropagation()` on hover over `child-one`

Comment: All the logic is working fine, BUT now i need to hide the parent class, When the child-two class is visible.

Comment: that would hide all elements within the parent as well

Comment: Is there any alternative way for doing that. onhover of one div other div should not be visible

Comment: @taneerudhanunjay it's a bit unclear what you're trying to have happen. You want for "Some dummy text" to go away when it's hovered and the "show me only..." text to be shown in it's place? You just want the text to change on hover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like following snipppet?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#mouse',
  data: {
    showByIndex: null
  }, 
  methods: {

  }
})
```

```css
.parent {
  padding: 2em;
  background: violet;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="mouse">
  <div class="parent" v-for="i in 1" @mouseover="showByIndex = i" @mouseout="showByIndex = null">
    <div class="child-one" v-show="showByIndex === null">
      Some dummy text
    </div>
    <div class="child-two" v-show="showByIndex === i">
      Show me only on hover on "div.parent" element
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: showByIndex somewhat implies that OP wants to scale it up at some point. And I think this code will break as soon, as he is using more than two child-elements.
And for only two Divs the code could be simplified. `data: { toggleChild: false }` `<div class="parent" @mouseover="toggleChild = true" @mouseout="toggleChild = false"><div class="child-one" v-show="!toggleChild">Some dummy text</div><div class="child-two" v-show="toggleChild">Some other dummy text</div>` No need for the static v-for iteration

Comment: @D.Schaller Hey mate, did you try to put 3 instead of 1 in v-for? Sure there is many ways to accomplish this, but i think he is on right way. cheers :)

Comment: The question is, did you? Putting a 3 in there will render the parent 3 times, which is presumably not the desired outcome

Comment: Presumably for sure. But, I'm guessing,  if you put lets say `items: [{name: 'aaa', price: 111},{name: 'bbb', price: 222},{name: 'ccc', price: 333}]` then `v-for="(item,i) in items"` and `child-one {{item.name}}`, `child-two {{}item.price}`

Comment: fair enough, but wouldn't work as well.